# iPad Pro: Detect 50/50 split

Tags: ipad, size-classes

Is there any way to detect the 50/50 split when using Split View multitasking on iPad Pro? iPad Air uses the compact width and regular height size class, but iPad Pro uses regular width and regular height in all Split View variants.

More specifically I don't want to have rounded corners on my views when in 50/50 split. (http://d.pr/i/18ThG + http://d.pr/i/19OFL)
I use the readable content guide for the width adjustment of the views.

Comment: Apple doesn't think at all when they decide what methods will be included to the public API and what remain in the private API.

Answer (score 1):

What it worked for me was to get the device width and the width of the current window.

For example, using:

```
print("root window size \(window?.frame)")
print("screen size \(UIScreen.main.bounds)")
```

I get:

```
root window size (0.0, 0.0, 678.0, 1024.0)
screen size (0.0, 0.0, 1366.0, 1024.0)
```

Then you could divide the results 678/1366 ≈ 0.4963